# Is There A Way To Remove Duplicate Code While Providing lvalue and rvalue Overloads?

Tags: c++, overloading, code-duplication, rvalue, lvalue

While learning C++ I decided to write a simple templated binary search tree (bst) and encountered the following problem: I want to be able to *construct* a bst by both passing it an lvalue like `const T &val` and an rvalue like `T &&val`. Similarly I want to be able to *insert* lvalues and rvalues. So I ended up with a lot of duplicate code which I don't like:

```
/// copy constructor
explicit inline constexpr binary_search_tree(const T &val)
    : _root{std::make_unique<binary_search_tree_node>(val)} {}

/// move constructor
explicit inline constexpr binary_search_tree(T &&val)
    : _root{std::make_unique<binary_search_tree_node>(std::move(val))} {}
```

for the constructors, where `binary_search_tree_node` is a private member of`binary_search_tree` which then had to provide copy and move constructor as well:

```
struct binary_search_tree_node {
  T value;
  std::unique_ptr<binary_search_tree_node> left;
  std::unique_ptr<binary_search_tree_node> right;

  // prohibit creation of tree_node without value
  inline constexpr binary_search_tree_node() = delete;

  /// copy constructor
  explicit inline constexpr binary_search_tree_node(const T &val)
      : value{val}, left{nullptr}, right{nullptr} {}

  /// move constructor
  explicit inline constexpr binary_search_tree_node(T &&val)
      : value{std::move(val)}, left{nullptr}, right{nullptr} {}
};
```

Also:

```
inline constexpr void insert(const T &v) {
  if (!_root) {
    _root = std::make_unique<binary_search_tree_node>(v);
    ++_size;
  } else {
    insert(_root, v);
  }
}

inline constexpr void insert(T &&v) {
  if (!_root) {
    _root = std::make_unique<binary_search_tree_node>(std::move(v));
    ++_size;
  } else {
    insert(_root, std::move(v));
  }
}
```

for the insert functions.

The list goes on when I want to search a value: Should I provide overloads for `find(const T &val)` **and** `find(T &&val)`..?

> So my question is whether there is a way of combining these overloads or any
>   other way to remove this duplicate code?

I read about [reference collapsing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing) but I am not sure whether I could make use of this concept here.

Any other thoughts or suggestions are also appreciated.

Comment: Small note: `inline` is redundant in the case of `constexpr` functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use reference collapsing to reduce the amount of function written.

For example, your function insert can use a rvalue reference + immediate context to leverage reference collapsing, resulting in a forwarding reference:

```
template<typename U>
inline constexpr void insert(U &&v) { // v is a forwarding reference
    if (!_root) {
        // we use std::forward to keep rvalue-ness
        // of the named object when v is an rvalue, but not when it's a lvalue
        _root = std::make_unique<binary_search_tree_node>(std::forward<U>(v));
        ++_size;
    } else {
        insert(_root, std::forward<U>(v));
    }
}
```

Even though the parameter is using an rvalue reference, lvalue will work here because of the reference collapsing. If `U` deduces to `int&`, then the parameter is kind of `int& &&`, which collapse to `int&`. On the contrary, if an rvalue is sent, it will deduce `int` as `U` so the parameter is `int &&`.

This pattern is called a forwarding reference.

As you can see, such code only has that property if template argument deduction is there for the forwarding parameter.

Be aware that making it a template will make it accept more types than anticipated if not constrained correctly.

You can also use a copy then move to avoid code duplication:

```
inline constexpr void insert(const T &v) {
    T copy = v;
    insert(std::move(copy)); // calls the rvalue overload
}
```

Comment: [ProTip] Add a static assert to the forwarding reference to make sure `U` is a the expected type.  That way you can do yourself a favor and get an easy to understand diagnostic instead of what the compiler will give you when you pass the wrong thing to `insert`

Comment: You can also do `insert(T v) { insert(std::move(v));}` and spare yourself the manual copy

Comment: @NathanOliver So when I want to insert an lvalue like `int value{3};` and then `bst.insert(value)` I myself would have to _move_ `value` into into the insert function right? In other words: If I want to create a copy of the value when I get an lvalue and move it when I get an rvalue I guess I won't get away without declaring both functions?

Comment: @SebastianWilke Not exactly. If you move `value` into `insert`, you will insert using the rvalue version. The forwarding version will save you the duplicate code, but will compile down to two (or more) distinct functions. The copy + move will alway move into the insert function, but will copy before. It's not a direct construction from an lvalue since you pass the copy as an rvalue but should result in the same thing.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot So your suggestion is to have _both_ of the functions you mentioned in your answer? Otherwise I don't see how _only_ the upper version can accept lvalues since it uses `T &&v`.

Comment: @SebastianWilke the upper version accept both lvalue and rvalue references. Calling the upper function with an lvalue will cause deduction to deduce `int&`. Then reference collapsing kicks in: `int&  + &&` gives `int&`. So calling the top function with lvalues, rvalue, const and non const all work. It will do as intended as long as you use `std::forward` to not loose value category properties.

Comment: @SebastianWilke I edited the answer to explain why the upper version also accept lvalue

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Thank you for the clarification! Than the error is somewhere else.. I have only your upper version in place right now but when trying to do `binary_search_tree<int> bst{42};  int value = 3;  bst.insert(value);` I get `no matching member function for call to 'insert'` on clang and `cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int&&’ to lvalue of type ‘int’` on gcc. My private insert looks like this `insert(std::unique_ptr<binary_search_tree_node> &btn, T &&val)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208086/discussion-between-sebastianwilke-and-guillaume-racicot).